# makefile, multiple inputs, one output. keeping fresh state. possible?

Tags: build, makefile, wildcard, gnu-make

I have one target that takes several input files and generate one.

right now i'm ignoring the freshness state of the input files and running it as a .PHONY

```
file.out:
    $(CMD) input/* file.out
```

i'd like to have something like:

```
file.out: $(wildcard input/*)
    $(CMD) $^ $@
```

...So that make would not run CMD every time the input haven't changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the .PHONY target.

```
CMD := cat

file.out: $(wildcard input/*)
    $(CMD) $^ > $@
```

Comment: forgot to mention that the rule with the dependencies i wasn't using .PHONY... i was expecting some answer saying that wildcard does not work like that.. but yeah, it works. no idea why it didn't work the first time i wrote it. probably i had a typo and assumed some weird make behaviour... thanks! will accept when the minimum time passes